# What is means by 'Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app is a Windows experience'

Tags: windows-10, uwp

In this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn726767.aspx

it is said 'Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app is a Windows experience'.What is actually Windows experience means?

Comment: Not familiar with these concepts at all, but I would throw my money that it just means *Windows experience* as in what a user experiences using Windows

Comment: Horrible marketing speak.  UWP is simply WinRT version 2.0.  They had to think of something else, WinRT was a giant failure.

Answer (score 4):

Well, basically what it means is; That by creating a UWP you are creating an app that will run across the Windows Platforms, thus giving the full Windows experience. Having an app that gives a familiar "experience" across all the devices that support Windows UWP (Xbox One, PC, Tablet, Phone, IoT, HoloLens) that is the goal.

Comment: UWP makes having a device that can run on multiple families of devices possible but that is definitely not the goal for all apps. There are very few cases where you'd want the same app on all types of devices and lots of cases where it wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft’s language around Windows has changed in the last year. Where Windows was originally a brand indicating an interconnected system of software, it is now used philosophically to represent the mission statement to let people do more.

The idea is, because of the Windows experience, developers can create software that operates in a new paradigm. More specifically, users can experience software in a way that centers around them as a user and not the device they are using.

This new workflow approach downplays the built-in interoperability of Microsoft products, and highlights the opportunity to create software that can do far more to change the way users and companies leverage and experience software.

At its heart, the Windows experience, is the experience that defines a better way to use software. This is a subjective thing depending on the type of user or industry – but it is also a far more broad-reaching definition that no longer simply implies: “build an app that can run on multiple devices”.

Good job teasing out this new language. Not everyone has noticed yet.

[image]

At the core of the Universal Windows Platform is the technology enabling code written for one Windows device to seamlessly transition to other devices and form factors. The Windows experience is the full panoply of Microsoft services, including those targeting iOS, Android, and traditionally competing products like Sales Force.

> PS: the Windows Experience is *not* the performance measurement tool introduced in Vista to evaluate hardware for its readiness for an advanced graphics, etc.

The Windows experience, in the new mission-oriented form, is intended to promote a love for Windows - but thinking of Windows not as an Operating System, but, instead, as a family of reliable solutions. It's a nice change, and I (personally) am excited to see how it inspires developers.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the intention is to encourage those creating software to not think about an isolated app that just runs on a single device (or class of devices) but to create an "experience" that can travel with the user across multiple devices.

For example, don't just think about creating a phone app or a desktop/tablet app. Instead think about how the user will experience interacting with your software (and presumably the same data) as they use different devices, in the Windows 10 family, at different times and in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Windows as an ecosystem has been moving closer and closer together in terms of developing for different devices for years.  With Windows 10, you finally have a true universal platform where you can develop for phones, tablets, desktops, HoloLens, Xbox, etc with one code base.  Sure, there are specific API tweaks, but those devices run the same core allowing you the developer to create experiences across multiple different devices!